# filtering a list if a parameter is not empty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
list.filterIfNotEmpty(module) { it.name.contains(module!!, ignoreCase = true) }
    .filterIfNotEmpty(repoUrl) { it.repo.contains(repoUrl!!, ignoreCase = true) }
    .filterIfNotEmpty(owner) { it.owner.contains(owner!!, ignoreCase = true) }

fun <T> List<T>.filterIfNotEmpty(value: String?, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
  return when {
    value.isNullOrBlank() -> this
    else -> filterTo(ArrayList<T>(), predicate)
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure `!!` is not a good idea, but not sure how to avoid it without a mutable list.
Any idea?

EDIT:

This is the idea I currently have, not sure if it is so readable or not:

```
list.filterIfCriteriaNotEmpty(module) { it.name }
    .filterIfCriteriaNotEmpty(repoUrl) { it.repo }
    .filterIfCriteriaNotEmpty(owner) { it.owner }

fun <T> List<T>.filterIfCriteriaNotEmpty(filter: String?, stringProducer: (T) -> String): List<T> {
  return when {
    filter == null || filter.isBlank() -> this
    else -> this.filter { stringProducer(it).contains(filter, ignoreCase = true) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the variables you're using are mutable, you should be fine using `!!` here, as the predicate lambda won't ever be invoked if their value was null in the first place.

You could work around having that there by getting the `value` back from the `filterIsNotEmpty` function inside your predicate, for example:

```
fun <T> List<T>.filterIfNotEmpty(value: String?, predicate: (String, T) -> Boolean): List<T> {
    return when {
        value == null || value.isBlank() -> this
        else -> filter { predicate(value, it) }
    }
}
```

The downside being that you have to call the function more verbosely:

```
list.filterIfNotEmpty(module) { value, element -> element.name.contains(value, ignoreCase = true) }
```